# Alternative to Switch-Case Packet Handling

Tags: c#, json, sockets, switch-statement, packet

I've been toying around with network sockets, with most of my issues coming from Windows Forms, but I've looked into a lot of programs like private server emulators, and I become dissatisfied with my packet handling.

Each message is formatted, in JSON, like so:

```
{
"id":201,
"Message":"Hello, World.",
"User":"System",
"Color":"LawnGreen"
}
```

"id" is a constant in all packets, and it will identify the function of the packet. Packets of the same ID, henceforth known as a header, will always have the same keys, but not necessarily the same values (duh, says someone).

I deserialize the JSON into a dynamic and perform a switch case on the header of the packet, like so:

```
switch((int)jsonPacket.id)
{
    case 201:
    ...
}
```

Given that this is a very small-scale chat application which won't even nearly begin to try and implement all of IRC's functions, should I still be concerned and dissatisfied with my implementation? Small games/testbench servers use the same method, but I don't want to be limiting myself in terms of functionality and performance, or if it becomes a nuisance.

Any thoughts would help.

Comment: You haven't told us what is wrong with the `switch`/`case` approach. And you've given us very little in the way of what a better approach means to you.

Comment: I suppose my question is really about the relevance of this code. I know it will work, but will it work _best_ for my purposes, given that I have seen other similar applications use an approach of using delegates and dictionaries. But it's been answered!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Using a switch produces a rather efficient code, so you would not limit yourself in terms of performance. It is also a rather clean code, in the sense that most readers with the basic understanding of the language would be able to figure out what is going on.

Another common alternative to switches is an associative container of delegates. You can make it like this:

```
private static readonly IDictionary<int,Action<object>> processor =
    new Dictionary<int,Action<object>>
{
    { 201, Process201 }
,   { 205, Process205 }
};
...
static void Process201(object message) {
    // Do something
}
static void Process205(object message) {
    // Do something else
}
```

Now you can use this array like this:

```
processor[jsonPacket.id](jsonPacket);
```

This will call the appropriate method based on the ID from the packet. You can make the `Action<T>` take a more specific type instead of the object, or pass a different set of parameters altogether if you decide to get more data from the packet before dispatching to the action handler.

Comment: Thanks. This is exactly the answer I'm looking for.

I've seen similar approaches like this used in game servers and I guess it was a combination of worry and jealousy that I felt. But now that I understand this approach I may end up using it instead :)